# How to select multiple options in Select2 dropdown on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, jquery-select2

I'm trying to load an array of selected items into an existing select2 dropdown, so that there are pre-selected items on load, but i'm struggling to get my syntax correct.

Give the following json array, which is $scope.attributes

```
[{"AttributeId":169,"AttributeName":"Abstract"},
 {"AttributeId":170,"AttributeName":"Animal"},
 {"AttributeId":171,"AttributeName":"Beach"}]
```

and the initial code to create a select2 dropdown

```
$(".attribute-tagging").select2({
    closeOnSelect: true, placeholder: ""
});
```

and the html tag for the dropdown which loads all available options.

```
<select class="attribute-tagging" id="edit-attributes" multiple="multiple">
    <option  value="{{attribute.AttributeId}}" ng-repeat="attribute in attributes">{{attribute.AttributeName}}</option>
</select>
```

This works, but I'd like to have 1 or more of these items already selected, so that on page load, all attributes are added into the select list, and then, for example - Animal and Beach are already selected.

Ideally an array I can populate which when passed into the select2 dropdown marks some of the items in the list as 'selected'.

So, in a nutshell

- Select2 dropdown is created, based on a list of attributes
- From another data-source, a list of 0 or more 'selected attributes' is loaded into this select2 dropdown, as the existing selection.
- A clearer example, 100 Countries of the world in a select list from 1 table, then an array of all the Countries user Bob has been to (from another table) is selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
  var $mySelect = $(".attribute-tagging").select2({
    closeOnSelect: true, placeholder: ""
  });

  $mySelect.val(["169", "171"]).trigger("change");
```

Now Abstract and Beach are selected

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiples by using **id**

```
 $('#edit-attributes').val(["169", "171"]);

$('#edit-attributes').trigger("change");
```

***Not forgot to trigger change event at the end !!!***